# Getting specific color for specific value using JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to identity incoming data and needs to apply exactly the same color for the same.

**Data sequence is in fixed order (but all may be present or not)** and need to apply fixed color mentioned like below.

For e.g. expected data sequence and color sequence is like below:

```
CLOSED           GREEN
VERIFIED         GREEN
RESOLVED         YELLOW
REOPENED         RED
IN_PROGRESS      BLUE
ASSIGNED         BROWN
NEW              BROWN
UNCONFIRMED      BROWN
```

So whenever `CLOSED` comes `GREEN` color should be applied, for `RESOLVED` -> `YELLOW` and .... for `UNCONFIRMED` -> `BROWN`.

Now the problem is all data may come and may not come for e.g.

```
CLOSED
VERIFIED
IN_PROGRESS
UNCONFIRMED
```

So written basic logic in Java script like:

```
if ( jsonData.search("CLOSED") != -1 
   && jsonData.search("VERIFIED") != -1 
   && jsonData.search("IN_PROGRESS") != -1 
   && jsonData.search("UNCONFIRMED") != -1 ) {

   colors: ['green', 'green', 'blue', 'brown'],

} else if (jsonData.search("IN_PROGRESS")
   && jsonData.search("ASSIGNED") != -1 ) {

   colors: ['blue', 'brown'],

} else if (jsonData.search("IN_PROGRESS")) {

   colors: ['blue'],

} else if (jsonData.search("CLOSED") != -1 
   || jsonData.search("VERIFIED") != -1) {

   colors: ['green'],
}
```

This will work for above sequence but whenever data would be different for e.g.

```
IN_PROGRESS
NEW
```

OR

```
RESOLVED
REOPENED
NEW
```

OR

```
CLOSED
IN_PROGRESS
```

OR

```
RESOLVED
NEW
```

etc.. many many combinations...

Then this will fail and apply wrong color to data. If i write condition of each and every data and respective sequence then i will become mad and its completely ineffective, tedious and very complex too.

## Here are the sample json data:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"VERIFIED"},{"v":16}]},{"c":[{"v":"RESOLVED"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"IN_PROGRESS"},{"v":14}]},{"c":[{"v":"ASSIGNED"},{"v":39}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}

{"cols":[{"label":"status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"CLOSED"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"VERIFIED"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"RESOLVED"},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"IN_PROGRESS"},{"v":26}]},{"c":[{"v":"ASSIGNED"},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}

{"cols":[{"label":"status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"IN_PROGRESS"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"NEW"},{"v":8}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}

{"cols":[{"label":"status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"RESOLVED"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"IN_PROGRESS"},{"v":9}]},{"c":[{"v":"ASSIGNED"},{"v":15}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}

{"cols":[{"label":"status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"VERIFIED"},{"v":6}]},{"c":[{"v":"IN_PROGRESS"},{"v":40}]},{"c":[{"v":"ASSIGNED"},{"v":7}]},{"c":[{"v":"NEW"},{"v":8}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}

{"cols":[{"label":"status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"CLOSED"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"VERIFIED"},{"v":35}]},{"c":[{"v":"RESOLVED"},{"v":15}]},{"c":[{"v":"IN_PROGRESS"},{"v":92}]},{"c":[{"v":"ASSIGNED"},{"v":63}]},{"c":[{"v":"NEW"},{"v":16}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}
```

Can someone thinks about effective logic rather than writing individual data+color for exact sequence like mentioned?

Please let me know if any questions or i missed anything.

Comment: why cant you process each and every line of data separately instead of treating it as a sequence.

Comment: How exactly do JSON data look like?

Comment: Because i want to apply color based on sequence. How will you know by processing data separately ?

Comment: Alex, thanks! I have added sample JSON data where all data having different status to apply colors.

Comment: should all those lines within your *sample json data* be processed at one time or separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that data sequence is in fixed order and you treat JSON as String, I'd suggest the following solution:

```
const DataMap = {
  CLOSED: 'green',
  VERIFIED: 'green',
  RESOLVED: 'yellow',
  REOPENED: 'red',
  IN_PROGRESS: 'blue',
  ASSIGNED: 'brown',
  NEW: 'brown',
  UNCONFIRMED: 'brown'
};

let colors = [];

Object.keys(DataMap).forEach((key, index) => {
  if (jsonData.search(key) !== -1) {
    colors.push(DataMap[key]);
  }
});
```

Please look at the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xq7hLo6h/1/).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks; accepted your answer! Extending to this, when i'm putting data in google chart. It doesn't accept the colors from data map. Can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673317/google-chart-throws-error-for-invalid-color-due-to-values-received-using-datamap ?

Comment: @Jits I'll definitely take a look soon.

Comment: can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816339/json-response-incorrectly-matches-partial-key-for-color-data as well ? Thanks in advance!