# Google chart throws error for invalid color due to values received using DataMap

Tags: javascript, arrays

Google chart throws error for invalid color due to values received using DataMap.

You can see colors: [colors], in options.

If i direct use color values like below then it works fine.

```
colors: ['#006400', '#3cb371', 'red', '#f5fffa'],
```

but if i get values through data map and it has same output then it doesn't work and throws error:

```
"'#006400' is not a valid color string".
```

Is there any kind of data formatting issue?

## Sample JSON Data:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"CLOSED"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"VERIFIED"},{"v":35}]},{"c":[{"v":"RESOLVED"},{"v":15}]},{"c":[{"v":"IN_PROGRESS"},{"v":92}]},{"c":[{"v":"ASSIGNED"},{"v":63}]},{"c":[{"v":"NEW"},{"v":16}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}
```

## Custom color (problematic):

```
const DataMap = {
    CLOSED: '#006400',
    VERIFIED: '#006400',
    RESOLVED: '#3cb371',
    REOPENED: 'red',
    IN_PROGRESS: '#f5fffa',
    ASSIGNED: 'brown',
    NEW: 'brown',
    UNCONFIRMED: 'brown'
};

let myColors = [];
Object.keys(DataMap).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (jsonData.search(key) !== -1) {
        myColors.push("'" + DataMap[key] + "'");
    }
});

options = {
    title: chartTitle,
    width: '410',
    height: '320',
    backgroundColor: '#f5fffa',
    is3D: true,
    colors: [myColors],
    chartArea: {
        left: "20%",
        top: "20%",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%"
    }
    };
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

## Direct color (works fine):

```
 options = {
    title: chartTitle,
    width: '410',
    height: '320',
    backgroundColor: '#f5fffa',
    is3D: true,
    colors: ['#006400', '#3cb371', 'red', '#f5fffa'],
    chartArea: {
        left: "20%",
        top: "20%",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%"
        }
     };
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

What can be the issue and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Could you create a plunker or jsFiddle for the problem? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can say right now is:

```
myColors.push("'" + DataMap[key] + "'");
```

should be changed to

```
myColors.push(DataMap[key]);
```

because values for each key from `DataMap` are already strings, i.e. `DataMap[key]` is a string.

Secondly, instead of

```
colors: [myColors],
```

should be just

```
colors: myColors,
```

because `myColors` is already an array.

Comment: It was typo from my end, i had tried that :) Thanks Alex again!