# JSON response incorrectly matches partial key for color data

Tags: javascript, json, object

Below JavaScript code matches to "COMPLETED" due to jsonData.search(key) !== -1 which is wrong because JSON response doesn't contain COMPLETED, it should show red color instead of green in the output.

## Reference:

[Getting specific color for specific value using JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672381/getting-specific-color-for-specific-value-using-json-data?answertab=votes#tab-top)

> Output:  ["green", "red"]
>   
>   Expected: ["red"]

## jsonData:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"sprint_status","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"NOT_COMPLETED"},{"v":4}]}]}
```

## JavaScript:

```
const colorMap = {
    COMPLETED: 'green',
    NOT_COMPLETED: 'red'
};

Object.keys(colorMap).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (jsonData.search(key) !== -1) {
        customColors.push(colorMap[key]);
    }
});
```

## Actual output:

> Color key matches to "COMPLETED - green" first due to search(key).

## Expected output:

> Color key should match to "NOT_COMPLETED - red" first.

How can I match with NOT_COMPLETED - read color instead of COMPLETED - green color?

Comment: why don't you parse the JSON string and work with the resulting object? Like `let data = JSON.parse("the jsonData string");` and then check `data.rows.c.v === "COMPLETED"`? Or is this question specifically about `String.search()`? I think you would need some regex then to complete your task.

Comment: Objective is to match color using JSON string. In this case JSON string doesn't contain COMPLETED, only contains NOT_COMPLETED but still it gives green color which is wrong due to search. It should exactly match with the data.

Comment: But why don't you want to parse the JSON string to recieve an object that you can check? anyway in this case you could just use`if (jsonData.search("\"" + key + "\"") !== -1)` as your if condition, but parsing the string is much more robust

Comment: This is what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/xq7hLo6h/5/ and gives your expected result. Do you get what I mean by parsing the string? This https://jsfiddle.net/xq7hLo6h/6/ instead searches the string for "COMPLETE" instead of COMPLETE (with colons) so COMPLETE doesn't get matched inside a "NOT_COMPLETE" string (which you could also do with a regular expression and lookahead).

Comment: Thanks Simon for trying to give answer. If JSON string has COMPLETED and NOT_COMPLETED both then also it gives  ["red"] color. Expected is to give color output as ["green", "red"] meanwhile.

Comment: if (jsonData.search("\"" + key + "\"") !== -1) works! You can add as an answer and meanwhile please accept the question too :)

Comment: Why are you not using a simple string comparison with the object instead of the entire string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This https://jsfiddle.net/xq7hLo6h/6/ fixes the issue by simply searching the JSON string for `"KEY"` (with quotes) instead of `KEY`:

```
if (jsonData.search("\"" + key + "\"") >= 0) { /* ... */ }
```

This way the problem with `COMPLETED` being found inside `"NOT_COMPLETED"` is circumvented.

However a more robust way would be to actually parse the JSON string in order to get the object and then check the actual property.